# Binding ObservableCollection to child window, design mode works, real data does not

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have the following code where the design mode works, but as soon I run it with real equal data the window just Shows the Default class Name **DocumentViewer.ViewModel.ItemSelectorViewModel** and nothing else (not unlike in design mode). I simply can't see the Problem.

### ViewModel

```
public class ItemSelectorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Document> _pictureSelectors;

    public ItemSelectorViewModel()
    {
        if (Designer.IsInDesignMode())
        {
            string xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(GlobalConstants.DesignTimeDataFile);
            IList<Document> list = ObjectSerializer.Deserialize<List<Document>>(xml);
            PictureSelector = list.ToObservableCollection();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Document> PictureSelector
    {
        get { return _pictureSelectors; }
        set
        {
            if (_pictureSelectors == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _pictureSelectors = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PictureSelector");
        }
    }
}
```

### View

```
public partial class ItemSelectorView
{
    public ItemSelectorView(ItemSelectorViewModel itemSelectorViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!Designer.IsInDesignMode())
        {
            Content = itemSelectorViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DocumentViewer.View.ItemSelectorView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:DocumentViewer.ViewModel"
    Title="ItemSelector"
    Width="300"
    Height="321"
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModel:ItemSelectorViewModel,
                                     IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.Resources />

<Grid x:Name="MyLayoutRoot"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"
              Width="Auto"
              Height="Auto"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PictureSelector}"
              SelectedCellsChanged="Item_SelectionChanged"
              SelectedValuePath="DocId"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DocNumber}" Header="Tagesnummer" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding GraphicType}" Header="Grafiktyp" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DocId}" Header="Doc ID" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

### And I call the child from the parent with a RelayCommand

```
ItemSelectorViewModel viewModel = new ItemSelectorViewModel();
viewModel.PictureSelector = _dataModel.DokumenteItems;
ItemSelectorView view = new ItemSelectorView(viewModel);
view.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
view.Show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ***replacing*** `Window.Content` (which is currently set to be a `Grid` with a name of `MyLayoutRoot`) with your `ViewModel`

When WPF goes to render the view model object, it doesn't see any `DataTemplate` for that object in its `.Resources`, so it renders it using the default template for all non-UI objects, which is a `TextBlock` with the `Text` property set to the `ToString()` method of the object.

You probably want to set the data layer behind your `Grid` instead of replacing it, so set the `DataContext` property instead of the `Content` property in your constructor

```
public ItemSelectorView(ItemSelectorViewModel itemSelectorViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!Designer.IsInDesignMode())
    {
        DataContext = itemSelectorViewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Rachel, that was the solution! I was sure it must be a small thing but I did simply not see it. Showing design time and live data works now like a charm.